# Rad tab OnClientTabSelected event should not hit server side code

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Hi,

I am using **Telerik rad tabs** control in my page where I am using its `RadTabStrip1_TabClick` and `OnClientTabSelected` both. For one tab I have to use server side code and for others I just need the `OnClientTabSelected` event and it should not fire the server side code,so my question is that how I restrict the code to reach server side for those tab click where I don't need server side code.

I have used return false but it didn't work;

```
 function onClientTabSelected(sender, args) {
            //set tab value

            var tabText = args.get_tab().get_index();

            var tab = sender.get_selectedTab().get_text();


            if (tab == 'Posts') { 

            ShowPostLinks();
        return false;
//stop hitting server side code

            } 
            if (tab == "Linkings") { 
        return true;
//go to server side
            } 


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with most Telerik client-side events you need to do `args.set_cancel(true);` instead of `return false`.

They have really good [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-client-side-basics.html) you can find most answers in.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply that was good, but now when I select the tab which should not fire the server side code then my javascript function is calling and it restrict to go to server side but only issue is that the tab selected css (which highlights the current tab) is not working it stays highlighted the last clicked tab(where server side code is hit)

Comment: are you doing `tab.select();` before cancelling event? if so and it doesn't work than perhaps change the CSS class using javascript?

Comment: hi, 
yeah exactly I used tab.select(); but it didn't highlighted the tab.
my skin is "Hay" and there is no custom css for me to get highlighted the current selected tab, please tell me a way to get highlighted the current tab either it hit server side code or it just cancel to go to code.

Comment: this might work tab.CssClass = tab.SelectedCssClass but I don't know if it'll stay with SelectedCssClass after you leave the tab.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [OnClientTabSelecting](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-onclienttabselecting.html) event which allows cancelling. The OnClientTabSelected event is raised "after" the tab has been selected thus you cannot stop the actual selection at that time.